# Can I configure ECS to automatically purge old container [images] from my EC2 instances?

Tags: docker, amazon-ecs

I have what feels like a fairly standard ECS deployment:

- My cluster is backed by two EC2 instances, both running CoreOS with the ECS agent
- The cluster has a handful of services, each of which has associated tasks
- Each service is running one task at a time – usually the latest task definition
- The container images used in my task definitions are hosted in ECR

Several times now I’ve gone to deploy a new instance of a service, only to have ECS get unhappy because it’s unable to find space on my EC2 instance for the new image – I get “No space left on device” errors in CloudWatch.

If I SSH into the instance, I find that it’s got an old copy of all my Docker images and containers – almost 100 of the former, 500 of the latter. I can free up disk space by running the `docker rm` and `docker rmi` commands manually, but I naively assumed this was the sort of thing ECS would manage for me.

When I’m setting up services and tasks, I never usually interact with the individual hosts or containers – I trust ECS to schedule containers for me. I expected it would also purge old container images to free up disk space as required. (I’m aware this isn’t functionality provided by Docker.)

I could set alarms to monitor disk space on my EC2 instances, and log on to free disk space as required – but I’m wondering if I’ve missed something.

**Can I tell ECS to purge old/unused container [images] from my EC2 instances?**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes!  Since version [1.13.0](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/releases/tag/v1.13.0), the ECS agent has automatically cleaned up old, unused images.  You can see the default settings and find how to customize them in [the README](https://github.com/aws/amazon-ecs-agent/blob/master/README.md) (check out `ECS_IMAGE_CLEANUP_INTERVAL`, `ECS_IMAGE_MINIMUM_CLEANUP_AGE`, and `ECS_NUM_IMAGES_DELETE_PER_CYCLE`).

Comment: Thanks! I’ll try turning this on, let’s see how we go. :-)